# How to add a fork github package to the pubspec.yaml?

Tags: github, flutter

map_view plugin is no longer maintained and let users with problems if the min sdk is up to 28, so luckily Eimji fork a modified version of the package but it's only on github https://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view and not on https://pub.dartlang.org I search to add his fork to my pubspec.yaml.

I tried

```
flutter_google_map_view:
       git://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view.git
```

Thank you

**Update**

I changed name by map_view it seems accepted ...
but when I use flutter_google_map_view I have

```
Error on line 1, column 7 of flutter_google_map_view\pubspec.yaml: "name" field doesn't match expected name "flutter_google_map_view".
```

I don't know why map_view "works" but not mapview ...So  I don't know if it's really accepted or the great methode ...

So now I have other issue when I upload my local map_view package ...

```
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':map_view'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)
```

I search buildToolsVersion '25.0.3 from my build.gradle file , but nothing like this. So I add buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' in build.gradle but have always the same error ...

**Update**

I remove all "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" it seem working and now I have this last issue :

```
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':map_view'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)
```

I think map_view is not correctly accepted ...

**Update**
Some suggestions to simply import this github package https://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view to pubspec.yaml ?

when I use

```
 flutter_google_map_view:
      git: git://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view.git
```

I have this error ...

```
Git error. Command: git clone --mirror git://github.com/munificent/map_view.git C:\Users\utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\cache\map_view-84b47933c6a730a2f0624a589576e53be480ad60
Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\cache\map_view-84b47933c6a730a2f0624a589576e53be480ad60'...
```

**Update**
I tried my last chance ! import map_view: ^0.0.14 (no compatible android X) and add manualy all modification did by Eimji https://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view/commit/5b631c499783936dfc462039274a6f5c59323068#diff-7ae5a9093507568eabbf35c3b0665732

I have this error

```
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':map_view'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)
```

Answer (score 23):

See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
      ref: some-branch
```

If `pubspec.yaml` is not in the root directory you can also specify a path

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/munificent/cats.git
      path: path/to/kittens
```

Comment: I have some trouble to understand sorry :( 

I tried 

  flutter_google_map_view:
      git:
        url: git://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view.git



I tried to clone and paste the plugin in my projet root

  flutter_google_map_view:
      git:
        url: git://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view.git
        path: C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\Myproject

but have a fail

Comment: If you cloned it to your local disk, use a path dependency https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages

Comment: I tried 

flutter_google_map_view-master:
     path: C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\myproject\flutter_google_map_view-master


I don't know if it's the correct syntax, in the example it's / but on my windows it's \
I tried all this syntax

C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\myproject\flutter_google_map_view-master

Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\myproject\flutter_google_map_view-master

Users/utilisateur/AndroidStudioProjects/myproject/flutter_google_map_view-master

Comment: Try a relative path `path: "../flutter_google_map_view-master"` (when the cloned flutter_google_map_view-master  is in the same parent directory as your project)

Comment: :( so noob,  the folder is in the root of the project... I tried flutter_google_map_view-master:
     path: "../flutter_google_map_view-master"   I tried   flutter_google_map_view-master:
     path: ../flutter_google_map_view-master

I have Error on line 37, column 9 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "../flutter_google_map_view-master". Unknown text at "../flutter_google_map_view-master".
  path: "../flutter_google_map_view-master"

Comment: If the folder is in the root of the project (same directory as where `pubspec.yaml` is), then you don't need `../`, just `path: flutter_google_map_view-master"`

Comment: I am desperate                                                                         
    flutter_google_map_view-master:                                                                     
    path: flutter_google_map_view-master                                                                                                                                                                                         Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "flutter_google_map_view-master". Unknown text at "flutter_google_map_view-master".
  path: flutter_google_map_view-master

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. Perhaps you can try to add more information to your question. Directory structure, the yaml code you tried with proper formatting.

Comment: I think it's not the right way to change name by map_view,there must be a conflic with the old name, a plugin can take the name who I want...normally I have to be able to select the name that does not matter his name ..
I come back to the starting box

Comment: You need to update the name in pubspec.yaml of the cloned package. Why do you want to rename amyway?

Comment: sorry i'm possibly not clear :) the original ( no compatible androidX map_view 0.0.14 ) is called map_view. I tried some techniques to import the androidX fork of this package but his name is flutter_google_map_view ( fork by eimji . When I clone I place the folder in the root of the project beside the pubspec.yaml and I let his name (flutter_google_map_view) I call him in the pubspec.yaml  but when I did this I have error.  So I tried to change his name by map_view, and error change.

Comment: I'm not sure ... the name I search to call ref to the name in the pubspec.yaml of the plugin and not the name of the folder ?

Comment: The name of the folder is only relevant in the `path: ...` parameter. The dependency name has to match the name in `pubspec.yaml` of the dependency.